# Which should executed included first .where OR .Include

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following repository method:-

```
public IQueryable<AccountDefinition> FindAccountDefinition(string q)
        {
            return from ad in entities.AccountDefinitions.Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
                   where (q == null || ad.ORG_NAME.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()) )
                   select ad;
 }
```

But since I am applying the .include then .where, so I am not sure how the above will be executed?
Will the SDOrganization navigation property be retrieved from the Dataabse for the records that matches the where clause or the navigation property will be retired then the filter occur?

Comment: I recommend checking out http://www.linqpad.net, it helps you understand whats going on under the hood.

Comment: i download linqpad.net, but seems it will not understnad entity framework syntax out-of the box.

Comment: Use [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) or [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) instead if you want to easily see what SQL will be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter for the `AccountDefinition` will be executed in the database. For each row that matches the filter (not for all `AccountDefinition` rows in the table) the `SDOrganization` will be joined. The matching `AccountDefinition`s together with their related `SDOrganization` will be returned to the client.